# in vim press k after open a file behaves strange

Tags: vim

In vim, after a open a file, if I press `k`, somehow it was mapped to `^[[>1;2802;0ck` which will remove the current and above line and get into insert mode. 
I get the map from the `vim myfile -W a.log` command and look into a.log file.
How to correct this?

Comment: `:verbose map k` will show you if and where k was remapped. It looks like a viminfo problem to me, though.

Answer (score 0):

Vim custom mappings are usually written in a [“vimrc” file](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#vimrc), at `~/.vimrc` (or `~/_vimrc` on Windows). This file automatically runs when Vim is opened, and people often put commands there to customize Vim’s settings and mappings. Check if that file exists. If so, check whether it contains a command like `map k ^[[>1;2802;0ck`. `map` may be a different but related command such as `nmap` or `nnoremap`.

If you have a `vimrc` but it doesn’t contain any mapping command, perhaps the `vimrc` loads a buggy plugin. Rename your `vimrc` file so Vim can’t see it, then run Vim again. If the problem is now gone, you know the problem is in your `vimrc`. Delete lines in the file until you find the line that is causing the problem.